# How to prevent Symfony to append hash to URL

Tags: url, symfony, hash

I am developing a website on top of Symfony 2 and it is somehow adding a hash to the URL.

The URL

***http://project.localhost/web***

redirects to

***http://project.localhost#.UhueaxvktbU***

And this goes for both prod and dev enviroments.

What I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any fancy javascript?

Comment: Hard to fix with this infos. But has to be javascript or maybe .htaccess. Do you use any third-party symfony2 bundle? can also be a requestlistener bugging around...

Comment: I am just using a custom Bundle generated from console. I am experiencing this to any SF2 project I create.